# What is the efficient way to load data into Snowflake database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the efficient way to load data into Snowflake database?-

```
 using External table or directly files from S3. If files then format is suggested Parquet or avro?
```

Comment: "efficient" for what? dev time, S3 IO cost, latency, SF processing time? Do you already have you data in a format? or have experience exporting from your existing system, what is your existing system..

Comment: If you have an option between the two files, those vary too, but here is some references for setting up each file type if you stage first and copy into a table later: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-intro.html#what-is-avro (use VARIANT) and https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-intro.html#what-is-parquet (use VARIANT) Can you please edit your question to clarify it a bit more? I am confused what you are asking.

Comment: Efficient in term of processing.  To add more clarification to the question - our use case is to migrate the data from Oracle tables to Snowflake. Exporting the data to files  S3 and load these file to Snowflake or point external table to s3 location and load from external table to persistent table.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it depends, but this [Snowflake post](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Load-Terabytes-Into-Snowflake-Speeds-Feeds-and-Techniques) summarizes it well, I think:

> Conclusion
>
> Loading data into Snowflake is fast and flexible. You get the greatest
>   speed when working with CSV files, but Snowflake’s expressiveness in
>   handling semi-structured data allows even complex partitioning schemes
>   for existing ORC and Parquet data sets to be easily ingested into
>   fully structured Snowflake tables.